# how to store math function value in mysql using angularjs?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am creating invoice generator. In that I want to store the total,discount and all things in my database. 
Total and discount are calculated as follow...

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in data">
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Subtotal</label>
  </td>
  <td ng-model="subtotal">{{list.sale_price*list.quantity}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="list in data">
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Tax(2%)</label>
  </td>
  <td ng-model="tax">{{((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*2)/100}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="list in data">
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Discount(%)</label>
  </td>
  <td ng-model="discount">{{((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*list.discount)/100}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="list in data">
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Total</label>
  </td>
  <td ng-model="total">{{((list.sale_price*list.quantity)+(((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*2)/100))-(((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*list.discount)/100)}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:400px;" ng-click="GenerateBill();updateAll()">Generate Invoice</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to save the calculated values in my database.which means I want to store `list.sale_price*list.quantity` 's value.

js part is here..

```
$scope.updateAll = function(){

    data={
        qnt:$scope.qnt,
        subt:$scope.subtotal,
        tax:$scope.tax,
        dis:$scope.discount,
        total:$scope.total
    }
    $http.post("../POS_System/widget/updateAll.php?barcode="+$scope.barcode,data).success(function(data){

    });
```

please help me out...

Comment: Way too broad if you want us to write the whole database layer for you. Not to mention you have not provided any information about platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this....

```
$scope.updateAll=function()
{ 
     data={
                subtotal:$scope.product.sale_prize*$scope.product.quantity,
                tax:$scope.product.sale_prize * $scope.product.quantity*2/100,
                discount:$scope.product.sale_prize * $scope.product.quantity*$scope.product.discount/100,
                total:$scope.product.sale_prize * $scope.product.quantity+$scope.product.sale_prize * $scope.product.quantity*2/100-$scope.product.sale_prize *$scope.product.quantity* $scope.product.discount/100

         }

        $http.post("../pos_system/Widgets/updatedata.php?barc="+$scope.barc,data).success(function(data)
       { 
           //do your stuff here;
        });
 }
```

Make this change in your HTML part

```
<tr >
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Subtotal</label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" class="cinput" placeholder="sale price"  ng-value="list.sale_price*list.quantity" readonly="" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr >
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Tax(2%)</label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" class="cinput" placeholder="sale price"  ng-value="((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*2)/100" readonly="" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Discount(%)</label>
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="cinput" placeholder="sale price"  ng-value="((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*list.discount)/100" readonly="" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr >
  <td> 
    <label class="clabel">Total</label>
  </td>
  <td >
  <input type="text" class="cinput" placeholder="sale price"  ng-value="((list.sale_price*list.quantity)+(((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*2)/100))-(((list.sale_price*list.quantity)*list.discount)/100)" readonly="" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:400px;" ng-click="GenerateBill();updateAll()">Generate Invoice</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```